# How can I set a default value to 'scale on screen' when inserting an image?

Tags: lyx

When inserting an image, it always appears too large on the editor, and I end up turning the next setting to 20%-30%:

[image]

How can I set a default value to that field, so that every time I insert an image it will be X% instead of 100%?